# How to link the combobox database values to the textboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

With this database I used and linking it to a combobox, I don't know what the problem is with non-organized combobox content(some value in line and the others with enter) so how can this be fixed?
And I linked the combobox value to textboxes, so when I select the database value from combobox to display the information related to that value in the textboxs, an error message occur (specified cast is not valid). In another word, the information doesn't appear in the textboxs when I run the mainwindow.

[The Database I used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpfQT.png)

[The combobox looks like this when I try to select a value(non-organized).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B40Vm.png)

[The MainWindow desktop app Display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j8WC.png)

> The MainWindow.xaml.cs Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace BV_Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillcombobox();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        public void fillcombobox()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myreader.GetString(1);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where Subcontractor='" + comboBox1.Text + "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string clients = myreader.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                    string contactdetails = myreader.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                    string ponum = myreader.GetInt32(4).ToString();
                    string scope = myreader.GetInt32(5).ToString();
                    string projectno = myreader.GetInt32(6).ToString();
                    string zigno = myreader.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                    string amount = myreader.GetInt32(8).ToString();
                    string invoicedate = myreader.GetInt32(9).ToString();
                    string status = myreader.GetInt32(10).ToString();

                    txtClients.Text = clients;
                    txtDetails.Text = contactdetails;
                    txtPO.Text = ponum;
                    txtScope.Text = scope;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = projectno;
                    txtZIG.Text = zigno;
                    txtAmount.Text = amount;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = invoicedate;
                    txtStatus.Text = status;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> The edited Code of MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   namespace BV_Desktop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillcombobox();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        public void fillcombobox()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myreader.GetString(1).Trim();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where Subcontractor='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string clients = myreader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : myreader.GetString(2);
                    string contactdetails = myreader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : myreader.GetString(3);
                    string ponum = myreader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : myreader.GetString(4);
                    string scope = myreader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : myreader.GetString(5);
                    string projectno = myreader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : myreader.GetString(6);
                    string zigno = myreader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : myreader.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                    string amount = myreader.IsDBNull(8) ? null : myreader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToString();
                    string invoicedate = myreader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : myreader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString();
                    string status = myreader.IsDBNull(10) ? null : myreader.GetString(10).ToString();


                    txtClients.Text = clients;
                    txtDetails.Text = contactdetails;
                    txtPO.Text = ponum;
                    txtScope.Text = scope;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = projectno;
                    txtZIG.Text = zigno;
                    txtAmount.Text = amount;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = invoicedate;
                    txtStatus.Text = status;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
}
```

> [Here is the MainWindow Display for row num=17.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ire1i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code change the line like

```
string sname = myreader.GetString(1);

string sname = myreader.GetString(1).Trim();
```

You can not use GetInt32 for each column, you need to mach the type of Database column with .net(c#) types for example for varchar or nvarcher type column you need to type

```
string contactdetails = myreader.GetString(3);
```

Here is the link for datatype mapping

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

AND THERE ARE NULLS IN YOUR TABLE

so you need to check for nulls too

```
string contactdetails =  myreader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : myreader.GetString(3);
```

to Empty Text Boxes

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-7J69E9N;Initial Catalog=DatabaseInfor;Integrated Security=True");
            string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where Subcontractor='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader myreader;

            try
            {

                    txtClients.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtDetails.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtPO.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtScope.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtZIG.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtAmount.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = string.Empty;
                    txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;

                conn.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string clients = myreader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : myreader.GetString(2);
                    string contactdetails = myreader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : myreader.GetString(3);
                    string ponum = myreader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : myreader.GetString(4);
                    string scope = myreader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : myreader.GetString(5);
                    string projectno = myreader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : myreader.GetString(6);
                    string zigno = myreader.IsDBNull(7) ? null : myreader.GetInt32(7).ToString();
                    string amount = myreader.IsDBNull(8) ? null : myreader.GetSqlMoney(8).ToString();
                    string invoicedate = myreader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : myreader.GetDateTime(9).ToShortDateString();
                    string status = myreader.IsDBNull(10) ? null : myreader.GetString(10).ToString();


                    txtClients.Text = clients;
                    txtDetails.Text = contactdetails;
                    txtPO.Text = ponum;
                    txtScope.Text = scope;
                    txtProjectNo.Text = projectno;
                    txtZIG.Text = zigno;
                    txtAmount.Text = amount;
                    txtInvoiceDate.Text = invoicedate;
                    txtStatus.Text = status;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Edit the question you need to check for nulls too

Comment: I edited the code above can you check for me, it works but still there is a problem when i select the (value1) from combobox and then, go to select another (value2) the information doesn't change (the information from value1 still there in the textboxes).

Comment: Put a break point on this line of code ->string sql = "Select * from Tb_Sub where Subcontractor='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "';";< - and check if SelectedItem is changed when you change the item in combobox

Comment: Sorry my Bad Actual Query will be Like -> "Select * from Tb_Sub where TRIM(Subcontractor)='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "';"; -<

Comment: Thanks a lot now it works. But in the database i provided above in row=16,17,18,...,21 when i select one of those values from combobox, the textboxes appears with information of the previous selected (doesn't appear empty textboxes). Other than that, all other rows works well.

Comment: Look at new answer

Comment: I added the mainwindow display up for row=17 and in this row in the database it has the contactdetails but it is not shwon i mainwindow